# Corona SDK app restarts with JSON

Tags: coronasdk

I use JSON for save of best score in my game. And when best score is written to a file then the application restarts. What is problem? Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you saving that file?

It should be stored using the `system.DocuementsDirectory` variable.  So I do something like this:

`system.pathForFile("useractivity.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)`

This stores the file in a location that is away from your files of your project.  What I suspect is happening is that you're saving your JSON file within your project folder.  Corona SDK simulator listens for file changes in the project folder and will refresh when it changes.

You have 2 options:

Put the file in the DocumentsDirectory (best solution)

Turn off auto-refresh on file changes in the Corona SDK simulator preferences (not best solution)

Information about the Documents Directory: 
https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/DocumentsDirectory.html

If this answer solves your issue please mark it as correct for future people who find this answer through searches.